# Docker: how to create an image with storing some login credentials

Tags: docker

I have a base image of archlinux - archlinux/base

Now using this image i want to create another image where i want that image to store some login credentials

I have program called `sampleprogram`. It needs to get logged in. So first step to use this program is to login.

```
$ sampleprogram login
```

-- it asks for username and password

From next time onwards i dont have to login and start from the second step.

```
$ sampleprogram connect
```

will connect using the login credetials entered previously.

So I am trying to create an image with sampleprgram login is saved

Dockerfile:

```
FROM archlinux/base
RUN pacman -Syy && pacman -S sampleprogram
RUN samplepgrogram login (ofcourse i will be using a script with expect)


docker build -t archlinux/sampleprogram .
```

Once the image is made (eg: arclinux/sampleprogram)

then i want to use:

```
docker run -it archlinux/sampleprogram sampleprogram connect
```

Once this container is running, i will be connecting to this container from another container using --link etc to do some tasks.

Comment: Docker multi-stage build may solve your issue, see the answer below

Answer (score 0):

If your application `sampleprogram` take username and password as command line arguments you can use it like this by modifying the Dockerfile to set environment variables and use it to login then make another Dockerfile to consume this as intermediate container:

**Dockerfile 1:**

```
FROM archlinux/base
RUN pacman -Syy && pacman -S sampleprogram

ENV APP_USER_NAME="user-name"
ENV APP_PASSWORD="password"

RUN sampleprogram login ${APP_USER_NAME} ${APP_PASSWORD}
```

now build this using docker build: `docker build archlinux/sampleprogram:intermediatev1 .`

**Dockerfile 2:**

```
FROM archlinux/sampleprogram:intermediate-v1
WORKDIR "to your working directory"
COPY "src-path" "dest-folder-path" # copy any important folder/content you like to keep
```

then run docker build on second file: `docker build archlinux/sampleprogram:sampleapp-v1` .

Now you may run: `docker run -it archlinux/sampleprogram:sampleapp-v1 sampleprogram connect` without any credential prompt this time :)

**Note**: You application behavior is not-mentioned with respect to how/where it is storing the pass so `you need to make those changes in here` but the logic is you can leverage intermediate containers to do the job (a.k.a multi-stage builds) [see here](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#use-multi-stage-builds)

Answer (score 0):

**Don't try to store any sort of credentials in a Docker image: anyone who has your image will be able to steal the credentials.**  Inject the credentials at runtime instead, maybe using a volume or bind-mounted directory to persist a login token across container runs.

You cannot securely store data in a Docker image.  Anyone can trivially `docker history` to get the list of commands that created an image, or `docker run --entrypoint=/bin/sh` to get a root shell.  Even on extra-minimal images that don't have shells, anyone who can run any Docker command has root on the host, and can poke around in `/var/lib/docker` to find the thing you're trying to hide.

(Another answer puts the username and password needed to log in in Dockerfile `ENV` statements.  Those will be there, in plain text, in the `docker history` output for anyone to see.)

If you need to preserve state across container runs like this, you can use a Docker volume or a host bind-mount.  This might look like:

```
docker run -v $PWD/sampleprogram:/sampleprogram/credentials \
  archlinux/sampleprogram:latest \
  sampleprogram login
docker run -p 8080:8080 ... \
  -v $PWD/sampleprogram:/sampleprogram/credentials \
  archlinux/sampleprogram:latest
```

(which assumes the Dockerfile ends with something like `CMD ["sampleprogram", "connect"]` to set the default command.)